# Check if image exist then refresh the page Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension

I need a function that continuously checks if a specific image is displayed on the page or not
If it appears, refresh the page
Functions must be written in JavaScript
i write this code but it not work as i want

```
timer = setInterval(function() {
selector.attr('src',  'localhost/product/image1.jpg');
```

Comment: Please try to get your code to a stage where it is valid code. It doesn't need to do exactly what you want, but I think you're past the stage where invalid code is acceptable.

Comment: It's done some one post an acceptable code :)

Comment: Yes, people here are very helpful, but I think you're missing the point. You've been here for almost 7 years, you study at a university, and yet you cannot be bothered to validate the code you put in your question. Not even after you've been asked to do so.

Comment: Yes but im not a programmer i just write something to do my works not a big project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this once:

```
const imageSourceToCheck = 'localhost/product/image1.jpg';

function checkAndRefreshImage() {
  // Find all image elements on the page.
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

  for (const img of images) {
    if (img.src === imageSourceToCheck) {
      location.reload();
      return;
    }
  }
}

// Set an interval to check for the image every N milliseconds.
const interval = 5000; // Adjust this value as needed (e.g., 5000ms = 5 seconds).
const timer = setInterval(checkAndRefreshImage, interval);
```

Comment: I agree that this does what was asked, but it's a weird question isn't it? I cannot think of a situation where this would be needed.

Comment: The site has a timer and after some minute an error image will appear and need to refresh to pass that error and continue working